# Need help going thru a list of arrays and outputing

Tags: excel, iteration

hi guys I need help on coding this for work

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10                            
y n y y y n y n y  y          
n y n y n y n y y  n             
y n y y y y n y n  y
```

I have this data in excel and I want to iterate through these data row by row and output the top integer without skipping cells of the cells that has a `n` in it

so the output would be somethign like this

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10                            
y n y y y n y n y  y   2 6 8            
n y n y n y n y y  n   1 3 5 7 10     
y n y y y y n y n  y   2 7 9
```

I'm a nub to using excel macro and would really be thankful if someone could help me out wit this problem to save some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
y n y y y n y n y y
n y n y n y n y y n
y n y y y y n y n y
```

you can produce a second sheet, where you convert/translate n to 1 and y to 0:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

Then you can produce a third sheet, where you multiply the cell from the former sheet with the column header, which gives:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
0 2 0 0 0 6 0 8 0 0
1 0 3 0 5 0 7 0 0 10
0 2 0 0 0 0 7 0 9 0
```

Hiding Nulls should be an Option too, so you would end with

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 
  2       6   8    
1   3   5   7     1 
  2         7   9
```

Is this enough, or do you need to glue the result together?

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 Glueing
  2       6   8     2 6 8
1   3   5   7     1 1 3 5 7 
  2         7   9   2 7 9
```

There are string concatenation functions, but can/must the result be glued together in a single field, or do you need one field per value? However, if the glueing brings the Zeros back, you can suppress them with 'if ...'.

You catenate togeter on a new sheet: 
In A2 A2', where ' marks the previous sheet. And in A3, A4, A5 and so on A3', A4', A5 and so on, but on B2 you catenate A2+B2' - the field to the left and the field from the previous sheet.

And this cell `cat (A2; Table4.A3)` you can pull to the bottom and to the right, and it will step by step glue together the whole expression.

You can link the result to the first page back.

Comment: i'm with you till the glueing part, could you elaborate more? thanks

Comment: the data i'm working with hold up to 200 columns, is there an easier function  i could do? as long as i display numbers clearly it doesn't matter if they are in the same cell or not thanks

Comment: Yes, I see, `cat` (I'm using the german version of OpenOffice, so the names differ here - I try to translate) `concatenating` strings does not take an area. I have a solution, and put it into the answer, not the comment.

Comment: actually i found a macro online that concatenates all the cells except empties which works great.
thanks for all your time and help with this task, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user851144: If the answer solved your problem, remember to mark it as solved clicking on the CheckMark below the answer score.